# Is it possible to define a pointer to a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I was reading `C++ Primer` and I noticed that there's a statement says:

> Because references are not objects, they don't have addresses. Hence,
>   we may not define a pointer to a reference.

But I just wrote an example code and shows that it's possible to create a pointer to a reference (the `d` variable).

The code is posted below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int a = 1024;

   int &b = a; // a reference to int
   int &c = b; // a reference to another reference
   int *d = &b; // a pointer to a reference
   int *(&e) = d; // a reference to a pointer 

   a = 100;
   cout << b << endl;
   cout << c << endl;
   cout << *d << endl;
   cout << *e << endl;
}
```

So, anything wrong with my test? Or the statement in `C++ Primer` is wrong?

I'm reading `C++ Primer`fifth edition. The statement is in page 52, 2.3.2.

Comment: @taocp oops, edited :-)

Comment: Switch `e` to `int &(*e) = d;` and you get `error: cannot declare pointer to ‘int&’` from GCC. That makes it pretty clear that `d` is not a pointer to a reference.

Comment: Think of a reference as an alias to the original object.  References don't alloc, dealloc memory.  As has been pointed out you can point to the object referenced by the alias name, but there's nothing in memory to represent the alias itself (it's only in code).  By contrast a pointer allocates memory and stores a value (even if the value is NULL).

Comment: included pointers and reference tag to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quote is right, since you're making a pointer pointing to the original object, not its reference.  The code below shows this fact:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  // two references referring to same object
  int& ref1_a = a;
  int& ref2_a = a;
  // creating a different pointer for each reference
  int* ptr_to_ref1 = &ref1_a;
  int* ptr_to_ref2 = &ref2_a;

  printf("org: %p 1: %p 2: %p\n", &a, ptr_to_ref1, ptr_to_ref2);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
org: 0x7fff083c917c 1: 0x7fff083c917c 2: 0x7fff083c917c
```

If you said you're able to make a pointer for reference, then the above output should be different.

Comment: Change the `printf` to `printf("0: %X 1: %X 2: %X\n", &a, ptr_to_ref1, ptr_to_ref2);` would make it more obvious :-)

Comment: Joining the usual stackoverflow nitpicking, the printf should have %p placeholders, not %x (64-bit pointers vs. 32-bit ints, yada yada). +1 anyway for a good explanation.

Comment: @yegle: Nice point. I have included this in my sample code. Thank you!

Comment: @Shimodax: thank you for pointing that out! I didn't know the `%p` argument before. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

What the book says is correct.  Your pointer is pointing to a, not to the reference itself (b) because the reference itself (b) does not exist in memory as such and has thus no address.

Comment: The reference *might* have memory, for example if it's passed into a function - the compiler may implement it as a pointer internally. That implementation is not exposed to you though.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't make a pointer to a reference. If you use the address-of operator `&` on it you get the address of the object you're referencing, not the reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a reference as an alias to the original object. References don't alloc, dealloc memory. As has been pointed out you can point to the object referenced by the alias name, but there's nothing in memory to represent the alias itself (it's only in code). By contrast a pointer allocates memory and stores a value (even if the value is NULL).